# HDMI Vertical PCB Connector

Tags: pcb, hdmi

I have a PCB that needs a number of connecting sockets (a mixture of mini-DIN, XLR and HDMI) but real estate is limited.  I was thinking of using the HDMI sockets as a means of reliably getting large number of connectors into a small space (as there are 8 connectors that need to be plugged in and the cables are also cheaply available and don't need to be custom made).

The cables need to be plugged into the PCB vertically (there isn't enough space to get all the connectors along an edge).  I therefore want a [vertical HDMI PCB socket](http://www.toby.co.uk/content/catalogue/products.aspx?series=HDMI-VTB-19S-GN-5).  The unit cost of this connector seems to be much greater than for comparable horizontal connectors.  I can find other connectors that have "wings" on the sides like this:[HDMI connector with wings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gd4iP.jpg), but these use up too much space.

Has anyone come across connectors such as these? Can you recommend a source for these?  Or have any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider a stacked connector with two hdmi ports, one on top of the other. I found one like that: [TI 1888811-1 HDMI Receptacle on Newark](https://www.newark.com/jsp/search/productdetail.jsp?SKU=51R0434) for $6.49 ($3.25 per port). While this is still not competition for the most popular HDMI connector type in terms of price, it should be less costly than the vertical/upright connectors.

If you have vertical space another option would be to design an additional PCB board just for the connectors. Learning more about your constraints would yield more answers.

[image: TI 1888811-1 HDMI Receptacle]

Comment: Link-only answers are not recommended: Once the links die of link-rot, the answer itself becomes meaningless. Also, as an answer, this isn't really useful, it just provides two google image searches. Please consider expanding upon your recommendation with the *what*, *why* and *where*, maybe even *for how much*, rather than its current form.

Comment: Thanks for the input Anindo. I edited my answer to include more information. I can't seem to comment on questions yet so I can't really ask OP to refine his restrictions and requirements.

Comment: Yes, I noted the edit and removed my downvote at that time.